# cmd terminates when delete fails

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I have the following bat file mybat.bat that:

1) Stops a service

2) Deletes some logfiles

3) starts the service again:

```
@echo off

net stop "myservice"
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto error
exit
:error
echo There was a problem...maybe it was alreay stopped

rem sometimes the terminal simply closes when trying to delete the logfiles :-(
set folder="C:\stuff\logs"
del %folder%\*.*   /s /f  /q


net start "myservice"
if %errorlevel% == 2 echo Could not start service.
if %errorlevel% == 0 echo Service started successfully.
echo Errorlevel: %errorlevel%
```

I manually open a cmd.exe instance and run mybat.bat but sometimes it simply closes when its trying to delete the logfiles and the content of stuff\logs is not deleted. Any ideas on why this is happening and how to keep the cmd instance alive even though the delete fails?

If I wait sometime and execute the mybat again it typically works.

Comment: I can't answer a question that is constantly changing  :-(

Comment: the above is the final version :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few problems.  The biggest is, do you know you have `exit` just below where you stop your services?  Did you intend, perhaps, a `goto :label` there instead?

Also, try moving your quotation marks from the `set folder=` line to the `del %folder%` line like this:

```
set folder=C:\stuff\logs
del /s /f /q "%folder%\*.*"
```

Or, to delete subfolders as well,

```
set folder=C:\stuff\logs
rmdir /q /s "%folder%" && md "%folder%"
```

Here, try this.

```
@echo off

net stop "myservice" || echo There was a problem...maybe it was alreay stopped

:: Now that "exit" is gone, the console probably won't close any more.

set folder=C:\stuff\logs
rmdir /q /s "%folder%" && md "%folder%"

net start "myservice"

:: "if ERRORLEVEL x" checks if %errorlevel% is greater than or equal to x

if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    echo Could not start service.
) else (
    echo Service started successfully.
)

echo Errorlevel: %errorlevel%
```

---

note: The `net start "myservice"` code could be condensed like this:

```
:: (leave the carat in the emoticon.  It escapes the parenthesis.)
(net start "myservice" && echo Great success.) || echo Fail. :^(

echo Errorlevel: %errorlevel%
```

See [conditional execution](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php) for more info.